# How 2 lists can be joined using streams and 1.8 functions?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List` of Prices and PriceGroups.

```
static class PriceGroup {
    String priceName;
    String priceGroup;
}

static class Price {
    String priceName;
    Integer price;
}
```

Below is some sample data, and an implementation I wrote finding the lowest Price for each PriceGroup. Any suggestions how I could refactor this to utilize streams to join this data?

```
List<PriceGroup> priceGroups = Arrays.asList(
        new PriceGroup("F1", "Friends"),
        new PriceGroup("F2", "Friends"),
        new PriceGroup("O1", "Others"),
        new PriceGroup("O2", "Others"));

List<Price> prices = Arrays.asList(
        new Price("F1", 100),
        new Price("F2", 150),
        new Price("O1", 250),
        new Price("O2", 300));

public Map<String, Integer> getBestPrices(List<PriceGroup> priceGroups, List<Price> prices) 
{
    Map<String, Integer> bestPrice = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
    for (PriceGroup priceGroup : priceGroups) {
        if (bestPrice.get(priceGroup.priceGroup) == null) {
            bestPrice.put(priceGroup.priceGroup, 10000000);
        }

        for (Price price : prices) {
            if (price.priceName.equals(priceGroup.priceName)) {
                bestPrice.put(priceGroup.priceGroup, Math.min(price.price, bestPrice.get(priceGroup.priceGroup)));
            }
        }
    }

    return bestPrice;
}
```

For the given data, my function should return a map with:

> F1 => 100
>   O1 => 250

Comment: at first, please make your code compile. `new PriceGroup("F1", 100)` won't work.

Comment: List `Prices` should not be populated with `PriceGroup` objects - please correct your typo.

Comment: Sorry, corrected.

Comment: second, I think `Map<String, Price> prices` and  `Map<String, PriceGroup> priceGroups` would suite your problem better, because you could access the elements by name, instead of iterating over them.

Comment: possibly, I wrote this only to ask the question of what is the java1.8 way of joining two lists on an id, and finding some minimum value from another list based on that id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get 2 lists joined you could consider to create dedicated object:

```
class Joined {
    String priceGroup;
    String priceName;
    Integer price;
    ...
```

Then, using `flatMap` you can join `priceGroups` to `prices` on `priceName` field and group by `priceGroup`:

```
Map<String, Optional<Joined>> map = priceGroups.stream()
        .flatMap(group -> prices.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getPriceName().equals(group.getPriceName()))
                .map(p -> new Joined(group.getPriceGroup(), group.getPriceName(), p.getPrice())))
        .collect(groupingBy(Joined::getPriceGroup, minBy(Comparator.comparing(Joined::getPrice))));
```

Now getting values from map you can print expected result:

```
for (Optional<Joined> value : map.values()) {
        value.ifPresent(joined -> System.out.println(joined.getPriceName() + " " + joined.getPrice()));
    }

// O1 250
// F1 100
```

Comment: An associative class shouldn't really be required IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

First: I think [@Ruslan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5108737/ruslan)'s answer is what you should use.

But you mentioned that the return has to be `Map<String, Integer>` and that the String should be the `F1` instead of `Friends`. So I tried to get it all in one go and got this abomination of a function:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getBestPricesV2(List<PriceGroup> priceGroups, List<Price> prices) {
    final String unknownPriceName = "Unkown price name";

    return prices.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            // map the price name the priceGroup name
            price -> priceGroups.stream()
                    .filter(priceGroup -> priceGroup.getPriceName().equals(price.getPriceName()))
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(PriceGroup::getPriceGroup)
                    .orElse(unknownPriceName), 
            Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Price::getPrice))))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        // extract the Optional<Price> to the price value
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().orElse(new Price(unknownPriceName, -1)).getPrice()));
}
```

Comment: On the filter line, I get `no method found` for `price.getPriceName()`. `priceeGroup.getPriceName()` works. Possibly this is the wrong syntax for the `price` variable? my idea does not seem to know that `price` is of type `Price`

Comment: @ab11 hm, you could try to provide the type yourself by writing `(Price price) -> ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply avoid using a join class for this operation and perform it as :

```
public Map<String, Integer> getBestPrices(List<PriceGroup> priceGroups, List<Price> prices) {
// create a map of priceName to minimum price value using list of prices
    Map<String, Integer> minPrice = prices.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Price::getPriceName,
                    Collectors.reducing(0, Price::getPrice,
                            BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))));

// use the map above to fill in the best prices map with values present or default
    return priceGroups.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(PriceGroup::getPriceGroup,
                    priceGroup ->
                            minPrice.getOrDefault(priceGroup.getPriceName(), 10000000)));
}
```

Comment: Assumption: Identity `0` while comparing considering the prices wouldn't be negative integers.

Comment: Wouldn't an `IllegalStateException` be thrown due to duplicate keys?

Comment: @Ruslan Well that's under another assumption that the `priceGroup` are unique, or else the value mapped would require a `mergeFunction`, in the OP's case a default selecting any value `(a,b) -> a`